# Azure Datafactory - Not showing all activities in dataflow, but it's there in the repo

Tags: azure-data-factory

am using Azure Datafactory together with Azure DevOps Repos.

Everything worked fine till now and all my changes i made in Azure Datafactory were reflected as commit in the git repo.

Suddenly, the Azure Datafactory doesn't show all activities anymore even if it's there in the git repo.

By checking the chrome DevTools, there are many issues mentioned:
[image]

Does Azure Datafactory interpret my git repo wrong?

**Example:**

The transformations, already there in the git repo, are not shown in Azure datafactory:

**Trials (already made)**

- Unlink / link git repo again
- Revert the last commit

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the syntax of the activity, parameters especially the dynamic one and the queries

Comment: See here for correct syntax of the activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801740/azure-data-factory-dataflow-interpretation-error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).