# Azure Data Factory - Dataflow interpretation error

Tags: azure-data-factory

Am using a data flow with an SQL expression. Recently, the Data flow doesn't allow this syntax anymore:
[image]

[image]

It shows errors in the Data Factory IDE.

Any idea how to come out of this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment and got the same error:

[image]

The issue can be resolved by entering the query in the query tab directly instead of dynamic content tab.

[image]

Data preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the query is correct.

However, there's a different syntax required whenever you are using the `expression builder` instead of the `query input`.

1. This is the correct syntax when entering the query over the `expression builder` - *Here are quotation marks required*:
   [image]
2. This is the correct syntax when entering the query over the `query input` - *Here are no quotation marks allowed*:

   [image]

**Some additional (background) info**
There's a different syntax using `expression builder` required, since everything what's entered there will be interpreted as JS expression - once you click "Save and finish" in the expression builder.
Example:
In this statement, entered via `expression builder`, there's the data type immediately recognized:
[image]